# Changing app to be Right to Left - Android

Tags: java, android

I am using Tab Activity in my android app, and I want to change the first tab that appears when I open my app, to be the last tab,but that the order of tabs will stay the same (swipe right to get to the first tab).
So in order to change the layout direction I added to the manifest

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

And to my Main Activity

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

What should I add / Change ?

Thank you very much

Edit: This is my Page Adapter Code:

```
    @Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            //
            return new Tab1Fragment();
        case 1:
            //
            return new Tab2Fragment();
        case 2:
            //
            return new Tab3Fragment();
        case 3:
            //
            return new Tab4Fragment();
        case 4:
            //
            return new Tab5Fragment();
    }

    return null;
}
```

And The Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3","Tab4","Tab5" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */

     viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
public static boolean isRTL(Locale locale) {
    final int directionality = Character.getDirectionality(locale.getDisplayName().charAt(0));
    return directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT ||
            directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT_ARABIC;
}
```

Comment: ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS is now deprecated, take a look at http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this to know if you are on RTL:

```
 public static boolean isRTL(Locale locale) {
    final int directionality = Character.getDirectionality(locale.getDisplayName().charAt(0));
    return directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT ||
           directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT_ARABIC;
}
```

Than just select the appropriate tab at the beginning.
like:

```
Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    if(isRTL(current)) {
    getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(4);
    }`else {
    getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(0);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have 5 tabs (tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4, tab5) and I want to change it so that instead of starting at tab1 the app would start at tab5 but the order of tabs will stay the same and by that in order to get to tab1/2/3/4 you need to swipe right..Maybe this would clarify my question.

Comment: How is the answer now?

Comment: What should I put inside The if(isRtl()) ? ( Btw I need Hebrew)